# Parallel testing on real Android devices using Appium

Tags: java, mobile, automated-tests, testng, appium-android

I am trying to conduct parallel web browser tests on two real Android devices using Appium and TestNG.

My code:

```
public class ParaTests {

private AppiumDriverLocalService service;
private AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
private AppiumDriverLocalService service2;
private AppiumServiceBuilder builder2;
private DesiredCapabilities cap;
public static AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;


@BeforeSuite
public void startServer() {


    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    builder.usingPort(4726);


    //Start the first server with the builder
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();

    builder2 = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder2.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    builder2.usingPort(4727);

    //Start the second server with the builder
    service2 = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder2);
    service2.start();

}



@BeforeTest
@org.testng.annotations.Parameters("device")
public void setUp(String device) throws MalformedURLException {

    if(device.equalsIgnoreCase("pixel 2")){
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 2");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "Fty4654541A00532");
        capabilities.setCapability("systemPort", "4726");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");


        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4726/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    if(device.equalsIgnoreCase("nexus 5")){
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 5");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "039fsef3543g8");
        capabilities.setCapability("systemPort", "4727");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");


        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

}


@Test
public void mobileTest() throws MalformedURLException{


    driver.get("https://www.testing7858494.com");
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    driver.findElementByClassName("mobile-menu-icon").click(); 


    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)", "");
    driver.findElementById("menu-item-613").click();
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)", "");
    driver.findElementById("input_6_1").sendKeys("Test");
    driver.findElementById("input_6_7").sendKeys("123456789");
    driver.findElementById("input_6_3").sendKeys("test1234567.com");
    driver.findElementById("input_6_4").sendKeys("Automated mobile web browser testing");

       System.out.println("Script has finished execution.");
       driver.quit();

}

@AfterTest
public void stopServer() {
    service.stop();
    service2.stop();
}
}
```

And my testNG XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">


 <test name="Pixel2Test">

 <parameter name="device" value="pixel 2" />

 <classes>

 <class name="Testing.ParaTests" />

 </classes>

 </test>

  <test name="NexusTest">

 <parameter name="device" value="nexus 5" />

 <classes>

 <class name="Testing.ParaTests" />

 </classes>

 </test>

 <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When i run this as a testNG suite, both Appium servers start and each of the mobile devices connect to the expected ones. However, the actual test itself only seems to run on 1 device, often two times. How do i get these tests to run at the same time on both separate devices? Am i missing something? I thought that the udid and systemPort capabilities would make sure the each device connected to the correct server and the test could be run on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with parallel TestNG + Appium + Android real devices tests because of static field.

> public static AppiumDriver driver

Try to make driver not static.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide thread count in **TestNG.xml** to support parallel run. Please add thread-count like mentioned below.

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" >
```